# stack with jquery - accordion

Tags: jquery

I have code sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tq5Y8/)

I want is when the accordion close color back to yellow.

"In the sample when i click the red to close the tab color will change to yellow"

```
$("#accordion > li").click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');

  $(this).addClass('active');
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

var animationIsOff = $.fx.off;
$.fx.off = true;
$('#accordion > li:eq(0)').click()
$.fx.off = animationIsOff;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle the class instead of unconditionally adding it. Here is a [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/9vfwt/):

```
$("#accordion > li").click(function () {
    $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');

    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
    }

    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
```